# Validate get_queryset GET parameters

Tags: django, error-handling, pagination, django-queryset

I am building an application that allows user to view certain records from the database. Since I want the users to be able to filter the number of records per page via the paginate_by attribute I also want to validate that input. Here is a snipped of my code.

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        q = self.request.GET.get('paginate_by')

        if q is None:
            return Syslog.objects.all()
        elif ( int(q) > 0):
            return Syslog.objects.all()
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied
```

Firstly I am getting the queryset and more specifically the paginate_by parameter and I am trying to validate it. When a user provide a positive integer or the home page the view returns the queryset. If the user provide a negative number a PermissionDenied is returned. The problem is that when the user provide a string, it throws a 500 Server Error.

What I am trying to do is to check if the provided GET parameter is positive integer or None (for home page), and if it is not to render a custom error template.

Regards,
Jordan

Comment: What your question is actually?

Comment: What I was wondering is why I get a 500 Server Error when a string is provided instead of PermissionDenied.

Comment: If you have got 500, show the error traceback

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using Django Rest Framework. In that case DRF has pagination built in which i would recommend using instead. [DRF Pagination](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/)

Answer (score 0):

I have figure it out. I had to rewrite the If loop in order to handle the 500 Server error that I was getting. Since the `q` parameter is a string when it checks it against  `if ( int(q) > 0 )` it throws and error because the int() method expects some sort of string.

```
>>> var="15"
>>> print(int(var))
15
>>>
```

```
>>> var="string"
>>> print(int(var))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'string'
>>>
```

The first example shows a correct conversion between a string and int, while the second throws an error and that was my problem after all.

Because it raise an error, I wrapped everything in a `try:... except:`  statement to handle it correctly.

Here is the code I ended up.

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        query = Syslog.objects.all()
        q = self.request.GET.get('paginate_by')

        try:
            if ( q is None ) or ( int(q) > 0 ):
                return query
            else:
                raise Http404
        except:
            raise Http404
```